# sed script to remove all lines with a pattern and append lines at the end

Tags: text-processing, sed

Files get messed up with multiple lines containing `foo` or `bar`. I want to remove all of them and append one line of each at the end.

So, given a file

```
some stuff
foo1
foo2
bar=42
some other stuff
bar
foo
more stuff
```

the sed script should return

```
some stuff
some other stuff
more stuff
foo
bar
```

I tried with sed `'/foo/d;/bar/d;$s/$/\nfoo\nbar/'` which works as long as the last line contains neither `foo` nor `bar` and the file is not empty.

How to do make it work even with `foo` in the last line? I'd like to stick to sed, becuase the whole script should do more than just this. Of source I could append my lines with echo after the script, but I wonder if there is no all-in-one-solution.

**Edit:** The empty file case doesn't need to be handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a second condition - delete only if not the last line and on the last line use `a`ppend instead of substitute deleting the line afterwards if it matches e.g.

```
sed -E '/foo|bar/{$!d
}
${a\
foo\
bar
//d
}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
( sed -e '/foo/d' -e '/bar/d' data.in; cat <<END
foo
bar
END
) >data.out
```

Deleting the unwanted lines with `sed` then simply adding the wanted trailing lines with `cat` and outputting to a new file.

Alternatively using `printf` instead of `cat`:

```
( sed -e '/foo/d' -e '/bar/d' data.in; printf 'foo\nbar\n' ) >data.out
```

Or, in two steps,

```
sed -e '/foo/d' -e '/bar/d' data.in >data.out
printf 'foo\nbar\n' >>data.out
```

This has the benefit of being clear and easily maintainable.